# How to display page numbering on top of the page?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I've been searching for quite some time now, but I can't seem to find an answer to my problem. This is how my page numbering commands are:

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

Now, the page numbers are showing up at the bottom of the page. I want them, however, to be on top of the page, in the header. Is there any way I can get this done? Thanks!

EDIT: I'm using the documentclass article and packages as seen below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\author{Mike}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[hang,bf,small]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
```

Comment: Usual packages to deal with that: `fancyhdr`, `scrlayer-scrpage` and `titleps`. Same information can be found when hovering over the tag {header-footer} on the left of your name.

Comment: It's important to know what document class you're using.

Comment: I added some more information to my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load `fancyhdr`. Commands for single sided documents were usually, for example (right head, left head, right foot, and so on):

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{}
\lhead{}
\rfoot{}
```

Although apparently the last three showed here are now obsolete.

There are other styles besides `fancy` which is used here, like `plain`, but you can make up your own style. `\fancyhf{}` empties the head and foot so you can fill them with whatever you want.

The new syntax has the following commands:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
```

`\fancyhead` is for the header, `\fancyfoot` is for the footer, pretty simple. The various letters are: `L` for the left side of the page, `R` for the right side, `C` for center, `E` for even pages and `O` for odd pages.

You can also add these commands for the lines:

```
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
```

You can enter whatever you want in the fields above, but you have some variables at your disposal so that nothing is hard-coded:

- `\thepage`
  Page number.
- `\thechapter`
  Number of current chapter.
- `\thesection`
  Number of current section
- `\chaptername`
  Adds the word "chapter" or the corresponding word if the document is in a different language.
- `\leftmark` and `\rightmark`
  These add the top level and next-to-top level structure number and name (though it can be modified) for the current document class. For example, in `article` it would be section and subsection.

Comment: The `\rhead`, `\lhead` and `\cfoot` commands are obsolete; `\fancyhead` and `\fancyfoot` should be used everywhere, with the suitable optional argument, that can consist of a single letter `R`, `C` or `L`.

Comment: @egreg Oh, they still appear in the manual though.

Comment: It's unfortunate that the author didn't really update the manual after introducing the new syntax. The new syntax avoids much of the clumsy code needed with the old one.

Comment: @egreg I'll re-word the answer then.

Comment: @cfr That was badly worded. I meant "left on the page". Thanks for noticing, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to renew `\thepage`. Arabic page numbering is default for `article.cls`.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[rh]{\thepage}% right header
%\fancyhf[lh]{}% left header
%\fancyhf[ch]{}% centre header
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}% remove if you want a rule beneath the header
%\fancyhf[lf]{}% left footer
%\fancyhf[cf]{}% centre
%\fancyhf[rf]{}% right
```

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[rh]{\thepage}% right header
%\fancyhf[lh]{}% left header
%\fancyhf[ch]{}% centre header
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}% remove if you want a rule beneath the header
%\fancyhf[lf]{}% left footer
%\fancyhf[cf]{}% centre
%\fancyhf[rf]{}% right
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: right header page number]

Comment: @egreg Not really sure what to say about that, to be honest. I really don't know what you're trying to tell me.

Comment: Oh, yes, it's an argument to `\fancyhf`! However I'd prefer `\fancyheader[R]{\thepage}`, which is clearer.

Comment: @egreg I find `\fancyhf` clearer but no doubt it is a question of what you're familiar with. Just because `rh` then means 'right header' whereas `R` just means 'right` and you have to look at the command to know right *what*. But, as I say, no doubt it is a question of familiarity more than anything. I always use this syntax so I'm used to reading it this way. If you always use the other, I'm sure that seems more natural.